# innerHTML working in FF but not in IE!

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, innerhtml

In my JSP i am using a custom tag `<showDateFormat/>`
like:

```
Date From:<showDateFormat/>
```

and in my common.js file i am having

```
function addDateFormatInfo(){
    var dateFormatHolder = document.getElementsByTagName("showDateFormat"); 
    if ( dateFormatHolder ){        
        for ( i = 0 ; i < dateFormatHolder.length; i++ ){
            dateFormatHolder[i].innerHTML = '<div class="infoSmall" ><span>(mm/dd/yyyy)</span></div>';                       
        } 
    }
}
```

so in my page wherever there is `showDateFormat` tag is used, it will display `(mm/dd/yyyy)`. It is working fine in FF, but not in IE. what could be the problem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell IE about the tag first. Add this line somewhere before calling `addDateFormatInfo()`:

```
document.createElement("showDateFormat");
```

IE will now initialize the element correctly - you can treat it just like any other element. Firefox does this automatically.

Here's the source blog post:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/getting-html-5-styles-in-ie-7

Support for `createElement()` starts in IE7 - though I works fine in FF3.0.15

#### Full Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Home | My Website</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.createElement("showDateFormat");

function addDateFormatInfo(){
    var dateFormatHolder = document.getElementsByTagName("showDateFormat");     
    if ( dateFormatHolder ){        
    
        for ( i = 0 ; i < dateFormatHolder.length; i++ ){
                dateFormatHolder[i].innerHTML = '<div class="infoSmall" ><span>(mm/dd/yyyy)</span></div>';                                               
        } 
    }
}

</script>

<div>
Date From:<showDateFormat/>
</div>
<div>
Date From:<showDateFormat/>
</div>

<div>
Date From:<showDateFormat/>
</div>

<div>
Date From:<showDateFormat/>
</div>


<p><input type="button" value="click me" onclick="addDateFormatInfo()" />
</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look about Custom Tags support in Internet Explorer.

> Windows Internet Explorer's support
>   for custom tags on an HTML page
>   requires that a namespace be defined
>   for the tag. Otherwise, the custom tag
>   is treated as an unknown tag when the
>   document is parsed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531076(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

what you need a custom tag for IE, using Namespaces:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:IETag>
```

and instead of plain:

```
<showDateFormat/>
```

use

```
<IETag:showDateFormat/>
```

cutom tags are much more powerful especially when bound to HTC behaviors, but unfortunately they are still IE specific, although you can manage to code something using JQUERY for all browsers, read more here:
[Using custom tags in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms531076(VS.85).aspx)