# Why is this javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, html, events

This is in continuation of the question:

[innerHTML working in FF but not in IE!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801960/innerhtml-working-in-ff-but-not-in-ie)

The above problem is resolved [ thanx to [pygorex1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212700/pygorex1) ] . But i would like to know why the following code snippet is not working.

```
if (window.addEventListener){   
    window.addEventListener('load', addDateFormatInfo, false);  
    window.addEventListener('load', loadNewElements, false);    
} else if (window.attachEvent){ 
    window.attachEvent('onload', addDateFormatInfo);    
    window.attachEvent('onload', loadNewElements);
}

function loadNewElements(){
    document.createElement("showDateFormat");
}

function addDateFormatInfo(){
    var dateFormatHolder = document.getElementsByTagName("showDateFormat");     
    if ( dateFormatHolder ){            
        for ( i = 0 ; i < dateFormatHolder.length; i++ ){
                dateFormatHolder[i].innerHTML = '<div class="infoSmall" ><span>(mm/dd/yyyy)</span></div>';                                               
        } 
    }
}
```

**provided it is working in FF but not in IE**
also, if instead of creating a new method `loadNewElements` and attaching this to load the event if i will directly write `document.createElement("showDateFormat");` in my javascript [ not in any method ], then the code works as expected [ both in IE and FF ]. Why it is so?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call **loadNewElements** before the other method.

If it doesn't work, write like this :

```
if (window.addEventListener){   
    window.addEventListener('load', addDateFormatInfo, false);  
    //window.addEventListener('load', loadNewElements, false);    // Don't need this for non-IE browsers
} else if (window.attachEvent){ 
    loadNewElements(); // Will always be executed before the other one
    window.attachEvent('onload', addDateFormatInfo);    
}
```

Comment: i have already placed `window.addEventListener('load', loadNewElements, false);` and if i keep an `alert` in `loadNewElements` method it get executed before `addDateFormatInfo`. Even then in IE it is not working

Comment: Do you place "window.attachEvent('onload', loadNewElements);
" before the other attachEvent call ?

Comment: @Fabien: see the code, i have already placed 'loadNewElements' just after attaching the 'addDateFormatInfo', so `loadNewElements` is always getting executed before `addDateFormatInfo`

Comment: Why would it be executed before the other one ? It is attached after ... Did you try to swap the two lines ?

Comment: Well, the docs are pretty explicit : "If you attach multiple functions to the same event on the same object, the functions are called in random order, immediately after the object's event handler is called." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx You don't which one is executed before the other one when using attachEvent.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try doing this:

```
if (window.addEventListener){   
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {loadNewElements(); addDateFormatInfo()}, false);  
} else if (window.attachEvent){ 
  window.attachEvent('onload', function() {loadNewElements(); addDateFormatInfo()});    
}
```

Comment: i will try this, by  tht time it is  +1 ;)